# Tesseract detecting 1 and 0 as L and O

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

In this image tesseract is detecting the text as `LOOOPCS`  but it is `1000PCS`. Command I am using is

```
tesseract "item_04.png" stdout --psm 6
```

I have tried all psm values 0 to 13

[image: actual image]

As per suggestions by other blogs and questions on SO and internet following clipping of image as well as thresholding is also tried.

[image: after clipping and thresholding]

[image: after clipping only]

Also tried `-c tessedit_char_whitelist=PCS0123456789`  but that gives **00PCS**.
But I am not getting 1000PCS. Can someone try these and let me know what am I missing?

Edit:
As per suggestion given by @nathancy, tried using - `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU` which worked on this 1 and 0 but failed for below image. It is being detected as LL8gPcs:
[image: another failing image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to preprocess the image. A simple approach is to Otsu's threshold then invert the image so the text is in black with the background in white. Here's the processed image and the result using Pytesseract OCR with `--psm 6`.

[image]

Result

```
1000PCS
```

Code

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Invert and perform text extraction
thresh = 255 - thresh
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me in layman words, how 0 and 255 values are affecting. And why cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU are added

Comment: I made an edit ... it succeeded for this image but failed for next image (both clips are from same image) so much difference is not there

Comment: It uses [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization) which automatically calculates the threshold value. It says if it passes the threshold we set the pixel to `255`. We use `0` to tell it to use Otsu.

Comment: Thanks.. I made an edit .. this method worked on first image but did not work for other similar image.. any suggestions?

Comment: You may want to try enlarging the image. This is working for me: `import imutils` then `image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)
`